# Adding a TextBlock to a Label in C# Code WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my code I am creating a new Label and formatting it and making it a child of a Stacked Panel. But inside of the Label I need to add a Text Block and I am having trouble to find out how to do this.

Using Code only I need to the WPF created by the code to work like this:

```
<Label Background="#000000" Foreground="#FFFFFF">
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Text Here"/>
</Label>
```

But I can not figure out how to get that TextBlock inside of the Label in the code, what I thought would work isn't working because it is a Label:

```
 NewLabel.Children.Add(NewTextBlock);
```

But this works when I use it to add the NewLabel to the StackedPanel.

The whole reason I need this to work is because I need text wrapping in the Label, but can't use just the TextBlock or other Control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the TextBlock as the content of the label to achieve your requirement.

```
Label lbl = new Label ();
TextBlock txtBlock = new TextBlock ();
txtBlock.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
lbl.Content = txtBlock;
```

Answer (score 4):

Also you could add a style for "Label" to your Resources which contains a default DataTemplate for type string. So all string content in any Label is wrapped.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Label">
        <Style.Resources>
            <DataTemplate xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" DataType="{x:Type sys:String}">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then all you Need to do is set the string Content.

```
<Label Content="A very long string for my Label" />
```

or

```
var Label = new Label { Content = "A very long string for my Label" }
```